# Getting cannot find symbol error while compiling the java source from command prompt?

Tags: java

I am trying to compile my SOAuthServiceImpl.java but i get below error . I have already set the class path to location where  XWikiConfig classfile lies
i.e C:\tomcat-6.0.26.B-RELEASE\webapps\wiki\WEB-INF\lib; Even when i echo classpath on command prompt i see same class path but still it is not able to
find symbol XWikiConfig. Though jar file(named as xwiki-platform-legacy-oldcore-3.3.jar)at location C:\tomcat-6.0.26.B-RELEASE\webapps\wiki\WEB-INF\lib
contains the file XWikiConfig(under  com.xpn.xwiki).

```
C:\XWiki\trunk\src\main\java\com\xpn\xwiki\user\impl\xwiki>javac SSOAuthSe
rviceImpl.java
SSOAuthServiceImpl.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class XWikiConfig
location: package com.xpn.xwiki
import com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiConfig;
                 ^
SSOAuthServiceImpl.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class XWikiContext
location: package com.xpn.xwiki
import com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiContext;
```

**Not getting what i am missing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add path till `.jar` in classpath adding path to jar won't do

Comment: but there are aaround 60 jar file this class file is reffering to.Should i mention each jar file entry explicitly.

Comment: better to use IDE and configure `build path`

Comment: Actually thats a server , i am not allowed to use IDE there.i remember during earlier days when we used to setup classpath we used to give it to lib instead of till jar file.But nore sure?

Comment: build using IDE then upload it to server